# Error on WebSocket connection

Tags: nodejs, websocket, api

i want to retrive data from this websocket api,
where is my code

```
    import { WebSocketServer } from 'ws'
let socket = new WebSocketServer('wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv');
 socket.on('error', console.error);
```

**when i run , i get this error :**

/home/bp/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket-server.js:81
throw new TypeError(
^

TypeError: One and only one of the "port", "server", or "noServer" options must be specified
at new WebSocketServer (/home/bp/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket-server.js:81:13)
at file:///home/bp/bp.js:201:16
at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)
at async Promise.all (index 0)
at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:533:24)
at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:91:5)
at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:65:12)

**ws version**
^8.13.0

**Node.js Version**
v16.17.0

**System**
OS: Linux 4.4 Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS (Xenial Xerus)
CPU: (2) x64 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
Memory: 1.00 GB / 2.00 GB
Container: Yes
Shell: 4.3.48 - /bin/bash

How can i fix this error ?

Comment: i got solution from where https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/2131#issuecomment-1475364391

Comment: import { WebSocket } from 'ws'
const socket = new WebSocket('wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv');
socket.on('error', console.error);

Answer (score 0):

if you have a same issues,
where is the solution https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/2131#issuecomment-1475364391

```
import { WebSocket } from 'ws'
const socket = new WebSocket('wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv');
socket.on('error', console.error);
```